# How can I use the contents of another html file in my input tag

Tags: html

Script to load html file

```
<script> $(function(){$("#FormNumber").load("rushform_number/number.html"); });</script>
```

I've been using this to display the information...

```
<div id="FormNumber"></div>
```

...but I'm wanting to be able to load it into this input as the value.

```
<input type="text" name="filename" style="display:none" value=<div id="FormNumber"></div> readonly>
```

**EDIT:**

I still can't seem to figure this out.

Here's what I've got now:

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $.get('rushforms/file_number.html', function(d) {
      $('file_number').attr('value', d);
      })
  }
</script>


<input id="file_number" type="text" name="file_number">
```

FYI: file_number.html contains only one character which is the number 1 and after a process is executed it gets over written with itself plus 1 on the next page in php.

You can check it here:
 http://tndeltasaerushform.com/rushforms/file_number.html

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `value` attribute of your `<input>` to the received html:

```
$(function() {
  $.get('rushform_number/number.html', function(d) {
    $('input').attr('value', d);
  })
}
```

Comment: I have multiple input tags on the page, wouldn't doing this also effect the other uses of the tag?

Comment: You could add an id to the input tag in your example and change the selector, I was just using the code you wrote since you didn't specify an id.

Comment: I've updated my post with what I have now. I still can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: You should use $('#file_number') instead of $('file_number') to select the input. jQuery uses [CSS selectors](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) to select DOM elements.